# argparse choices structure of allowed values

Tags: python, argparse

Using `argparse` in relation to [Python dependencies between groups using argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660876/python-dependencies-between-groups-using-argparse), I have an argument part of some parser group of a parser - for example:

```
group_simulate.add_argument('-P',
                            help='simulate FC port down',
                            nargs=1,
                            metavar='fc_port_name',
                            dest='simulate')
```

How it's possible to use the [choices](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#choices) to limit the choices to a list of parameters of the next structure:

```
1:m:"number between 1 and 10":p:"number between 1 and 4"
```

I have tried to use the range option but I couldn't find a way to create a list of choices that are acceptable

examples:
legal parameters:

```
test.py -P 1:m:4:p:2
```

not legal parameters:

```
test.py -P 1:p:2
test.py -P abvds
```

Thank you very much for the help guys!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can define a custom type that will raise an `argparse.ArgumentTypeError` if the string
doesn't match the format you need.

```
def SpecialString(v):
    fields = v.split(":")
    # Raise a value error for any part of the string
    # that doesn't match your specification. Make as many
    # checks as you need. I've only included a couple here
    # as examples.
    if len(fields) != 5:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("String must have 5 fields")
    elif not (1 <= int(fields[2]) <= 10):
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("Field 3 must be between 1 and 10, inclusive")
    else:
        # If all the checks pass, just return the string as is
        return v

group_simulate.add_argument('-P',
                        type=SpecialString,
                        help='simulate FC port down',
                        nargs=1,
                        metavar='fc_port_name',
                        dest='simulate')
```

UPDATE: here's a full custom type to check the value. All checking is done
in the regular expression, although it only gives one generic error message
if any part is wrong.

```
def SpecialString(v):
    import re  # Unless you've already imported re previously
    try:
        return re.match("^1:m:([1-9]|10):p:(1|2|3|4)$", v).group(0)
    except:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("String '%s' does not match required format"%(v,))
```

Comment: ok, thank you very much chepner for your comment,
I actually was looking looking for some like regex "trick" to check the value of argument, but defining an action is a solution as well,

Comment: You can use a regex to do most of the checking; see my forthcoming update.

Comment: Thank you for the update @chepner
that is an excellent example of using regex in an additional method that will check the legality.

Comment: Thanks. A small fix in the first example: if len(v) != 5: should be if len(fields) != 5:

Comment: you could replace `(1|2|3|4)` in your regex with `[1-4]` which is more concise

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you're simply looking for:

```py
group_simulate.add_argument('-P',
                            help='simulate FC port down',
                            type=int, 
                            metavar='fc_port_name',
                            dest='simulate',
                            choices=range(1, 10)) # answer
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices