# Python argparse regex

Tags: python, regex, argparse

Is it possible to use a regex for parsing an argument? For example, I want to accept an argument if only it is a 32 length hex (i.e. matches `/[a-f0-9A-F]{32}/`)

I tried

```
p.add_argument('hex', type=str, nargs="[a-f0-9A-F]{32}")
```

without success

Comment: Alternatively, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665234/argparse-choices-structure-of-allowed-values).

Comment: `argparse` does use `regex` expressions to count argument strings, but it generates the patterns itself.  The allowed `nargs` values like `*+?' have a regex feel, but they aren't used directly.  They are actually values of module constants (like `argparse.ZERO_OR_MORE`), and are used in `if else` tests.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type) keyword argument can take any callable that accepts a single string argument and returns the converted value. If the callable raises `argparse.ArgumentTypeError`, `TypeError`, or `ValueError`, the exception is caught and a nicely formatted error message is displayed.

```
import argparse
import re 
from uuid import uuid4

def my_regex_type(arg_value, pat=re.compile(r"^[a-f0-9A-F]{32}$")):
    if not pat.match(arg_value):
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("invalid value")
    return arg_value

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('hex', type=my_regex_type)

args = parser.parse_args([uuid4().hex])
```