# How to accept only string type arguments in Python 3

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to create some argument parameters for my python file. I only want to accept String type as arguments. Below is my code of foo.py -

```
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # options to the user 
    parser.add_argument('--source_table', type = str, required = True)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    params = vars(args) # convert arguments to dictionary
    print(type(params['source_table'])) # prints <class 'str'>
```

When I give string arguments as -

```
>python foo.py --source_table=abc
```

It prints

```
<class 'str'>
```

whereas, even if I type

```
>python foo.py --source_table=123
```

it prints

```
<class 'str'>
```

I would like throw an error saying that only String type is accepted.

Comment: `123` can be either a string or int though.  What if it's `a1`? Is it still a valid string? If you want only alpha characters you might want to manually handle with `str.isalpha()`.

Comment: If you are only interested in some sort of a pattern you might need to use a regex to check the validity.

Comment: A link in support of what @Idlehands said: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"123"` is still a string, but it seems you want to use the alpha characters only. You could check the input before you continue the execution:

```
import argparse
import re # regex 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # options to the user 
    parser.add_argument('--source_table', type = str, required = True)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    params = vars(args) # convert arguments to dictionary
    src_table = params['source_table']
    # check for alpha only
    if re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$', src_table) is None:
        print("bad input, alpha characters only")
        return
    # continue normal execution
    print(type(src_table)) # prints <class 'str'>
```

or you can make your own argparse type like here: [Python argparse regex expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881002/python-argparse-regex-expression)

**edit**
@idlehands points out below that `isalpha()` will be sufficient enough for letters only. If you want to allow `-`, `_` or  other special characters, then regex is still the way to go. Update the regex in the above code to be `re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z\-_]+$', src_table)` to match `-` and `_`.

Comment: `.isalpha()` is sufficient for the test, no need to use regex for this particular use case...

Comment: Very good point. I forgot about `isalpha()`. However, if there are cases where something like `test-new` is allowed, then `isalpha()` will be `False`.

Comment: `test-new` would also fail with your check, but yes, regex will give you more flexibility if you need it.  I'd say OP's question is not exactly clear to determine whether `.isalpha()` is sufficient or a variant of regex is required.

Comment: This `isalpha` test could be put into a `type` function.

Answer (score 0):

This requirement could be implemented with a `type` function:

```
def stringonly(astr):
    try:
        int(astr)
    except ValueError:
        return astr
    raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('only a string type accepted')
```

This is sort of a `~int` type.  It raises an error only if the string can be interpreted as an integer.  Other tests such as `isalpha` would be fine too.  I could have raised a`TypeError` or `ValueError`, but `ArgumentTypeError` lets me customize the error message.

It would be used as:

```
In [22]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [23]: parser.add_argument('-s','--source', type=stringonly);


In [24]: parser.parse_args('-s 123'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-s SOURCE]
ipython3: error: argument -s/--source: only a string type accepted
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

In [25]: parser.parse_args('-s foo'.split())
Out[25]: Namespace(source='foo')
```