# How to parse a valid IP4/IPV6 address using optparse in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, optparse

Like I want to parse `127.0.0.1` it can be parsed correctly but `127.0.a.1` is not a valid ip address so it should throw an error. How to do this using optparse in python?

Like to parse a integer or a string value we use

```
parser.add_option("-n", action="store", type="int", dest="number")
```

but for parsing a valid ip address what should we write?

Comment: could you use a regex to check?

Comment: @JamesLingham what should be the line I should use. Can you help me in this?

Comment: A possible regex for your case could be `r'\d{3}(\.\d){3}'` which means check for 3 digits, then 3 times a dot followed by a digit.

Comment: I would recommend to swap to argparse instead of using optparse. In order to stick with optparse, the type check explained in the question I linked has to be implemented following the steps detailed here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#extending-optparse

Comment: We can use call back to verify it?

Comment: What do you mean by call back?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/optparse-callback-example-6.html 
I was talking about this we can use it and verify whether it is a valid ip or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using this [section of the optparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#extending-optparse), this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14711925/2504700) (which adresses the exact same question with argparse) can be adapted to optparse.

The idea is basically the following:

1. Define a function that checks whether or not the input fulfills given condition (the logic is already done in the argparse answer, and the structure is in the optparse documentation I linked)
2. Define a new option for the type optparse parameter.
3. Use this user defined type for the IP argument

Therefore, the code would look like this:

```
from copy import copy
from optparse import OptionParser, Option, OptionValueError 
import re

# define checker function
def check_ip(option, opt, value):
    try:
        return re.match(r'(\d{3}(\.\d){3})', value).group(0) # I added some 
        # parethesis to the comment in order to define the IP as group(0)
    except: # I think re.match().group() would raise an AttributeError, check it
        raise OptionValueError(
            "option %s: invalid IP value: %r" % (opt, value))

# define new optparse option
class MyOption(Option):
    TYPES = Option.TYPES + ("IP",)
    TYPE_CHECKER = copy(Option.TYPE_CHECKER)
    TYPE_CHECKER["IP"] = check_ip

# use optparser with the new option
parser = OptionParser(option_class=MyOption)
parser.add_option("-c", type="IP")
```

## Comments

Check the error you get from the `re.match`, and write `except <error_type>`. It is not good practice to catch *any* exception (see [Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice)).

Also consider using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) instead of optparse, both work in python2.7. [Why use argparse rather than optparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217673/why-use-argparse-rather-than-optparse)

Comment: Hi Yeah I am getting an error. if I try to pass any IP like 192.168.10.10 or any ip value its showing invalid ip error.

Example:
python eg1.py -c 12.12.12.12
Usage: eg1.py [options]

eg1.py: error: option -c: invalid IP value: '12.12.12.12'

What changes should I make in the code?

Comment: The regex checks for 3 digits, then 3 times the pack (dot followed by digit). What should it accept? just any number of digits with 3 dots in between?

Comment: You can also check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean or this tutorial https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285 and check if they work for all your cases here https://regex101.com/ regular expressions can be really useful

Comment: For example, you may want to try `r'((\d+\.){3}\d+)'`, which matches the pattern: 3 times the pack (digit one or more times followed by dot) and then digit one or more times

Comment: Thanks sir yeah it worked perfectly.. I clearly understood about the use of regex for IP. 
Now I want to try to use argparse instead of optparse for IP address parsing. Can you please any links so that I can try?

Comment: You can start taking a look at this tutorial https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html. Then, as you can see in the answer I linked, the type option can accept any user defined function without need to define a custom `MyOption` class